# Interfacing SD card with arduino without shield

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sd-card

I am trying to connect SD card with arduino without using a shield. To convert to 3.3v, I have used voltage divider circuit as described in these two sites:

http://garagelab.com/profiles/blogs/tutorial-how-to-use-sd-card-with-arduino

http://www.martin-gardner.co.uk/how-to-connect-your-old-sd-card-to-an-arduino/

When I uploaded the code i got the following error on serial monitor:

Initializing SD card...initialization done.

error opening test.txt
error opening test.txt

Comment: Can you show us your code and circuit diagram?

Comment: ![SD card link](http://api.ning.com/files/-EF*0mGtsiMPkv6l0GSg7ymaIe2mhN0or-VPGvfYIjgFkbeXp*M*jbFETzaVSoNBEXSXLfNxl-pazf4u1khynSY0O4c*SdUz/TutorialSDcard.jpg)

Comment: The code is exactly of Examples/SD/ReadWrite

Comment: Is the SD card properly formatted. FAT or FAT32?

Comment: Yes, it has been formatted to FAT32.

Comment: Does your code use CS pin 10 as shown in your wiring diagram, or use CS pin 4 as shown in the martin-gardner.co.uk site code? It's related to the initialization code `if (!SD.begin(4)) {`.

Comment: @MarkU We have changed the code 'if(!SD.begin(4))'  to   '(!SD.begin(10))'

Comment: I can't understand what exactly happened, but i first uploaded CardInfo file from Examples > SD > CardInfo and after that i uploaded ReadWrite and i got the correct output.